How does the statement “After X I will do Y in Z hours” relate to the order of events?
For example:
“After I finish baking the cake, I will bake another one in 2 hours.”
or:
“After eating dinner, I will go to bed in 2 hours.”
Do these statements imply that “baking a new cake” and “going to bed”, will happen after 2 hours from the moment the statement was uttered, or after 2 hours from the first event “baking the first cake” and “eating dinner”?

These don't sound too natural. Sentences like "I will  leave for the station in half an hour" usually have the time of utterance as the temporal deictic centre (or an obvious alternative, as with 'He was late.  And the match started in just two hours.'  With the initial sequencing temporal ("After I have done X"), it is far more natural to use say "I will do Y for two hours, then go to bed" ... or one could avoid the 'after'-clause and use say "I will finish baking the cake, and then in two hours I will bake another one.”

It's natural to infer a causal relationship between the two halves. So how will eating dinner affect your going to bed? How will baking a cake affect your next baking?

They are ambiguous, and may have either of the two meanings.
However, unless there is some particular context to suggest it, (for example, we are doing some sort of exercise where our time is allocated in two-hour blocks)  I'm sure they would be understood in your first sense.

I see. I’m mainly trying to translate a bunch of statements from english as part of an exercise I’m doing. The statements I’m trying to translate precisely are: “George will lost the match, but after that, he will win the next match in two months.” And “The Italian team will win the match, but after that they will lose the match in 4 years” what do you think there meaning is here? Thanks

@ZaidAbubaker, I think in those cases it will be your second meaning, because the matches are presumably already scheduled. But it could be your first meaning.

"George will lost the match, but after that, he will win the next match, which is in two months" or "George will lost the match, but after that, he will win the next match in two months' time."

George will lose the match

You could instead say "two months later", "four years later".
